# PCA - Relation Between Variance of Eigen values and the effectiveness of PCA on the data

Tags: machine-learning, pca, data-analysis, variance, eigenvalue

If the covariance matrix has eigenvalues λ1 ≥ λ2 ... ≥ λd > 0

why is the variance of the eigen values, [image: var]  a measure of whether or not PCA would be useful for analyzing the data (the
higher the value of σ the more useful PCA).

Comment: That is an interesting question, but it is not about programming, but about statistics. I would recommend moving this question to `stats`.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143489/pca-relation-between-variance-of-eigen-values-and-the-effectiveness-of-pca-on?noredirect=1#comment274448_143489

Comment: Have you had a look at the first comment? It's actually a nice geometrical explanation.

Comment: yes good explanation but i would be more happy with maybe a complete answer